# Mocking an API call python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I have a class:

```
class Base(object):

   def __init__(self, api_key):
      self.api_key = api_key
      self.url = 'http://someurl.com/api/'
      self.inital_params = {"api_token": self.api_key}

   def make_request(self, endpoint, params = None):
      if params:
         params.update(self.initial_params)

      url = self.url + endpoint
      
      r = requests.get(url, params=params)
      response = r.json()

      data = response.get("data")

      return data
```

Now, I am trying to mock a HTTP request via this class.

```
import responses
@responses.activate
def test():
    responses.add(
        responses.GET,
        'http://someurl.com/api/endpoint',
        json= {"error": "not found"},
        status=404
    )

    base = Base(api_key)
    resp = base.make_request(endpoint=endpoint)

    assert resp.json() == {"error": "not found"}
```

But this isn't working. I am getting the following error: `requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: Connection refused by Responses - the call doesn't match any registered mock.`  What url am I supposed to pass in in responses.add()?

Do I have to pass in the exact url I pass in to my `requests.get()` function within `make_request()` within my `Base` class?

Comment: _What url am I supposed to pass in in responses.add()? Do I need to include the API key?_ This should be mentioned in the API documentation

Comment: You don't seem to have activated responses, for one thing - see the examples in https://github.com/getsentry/responses#basics

Comment: Does the url in the ```responses.add()``` function have to match the url I put in to the ```requests.get()``` function inside my class?

Comment: @jonrsharpe sorry, that was a typo. I've edited it now

Comment: That's not valid syntactically. Please ensure this is a [mre] that actually recreates your issue. Also expand on *"isn't working"*.

Comment: _Do I have to pass in the exact url?_ Yes.